# Explanation for devissage argument

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $K$ be a local field of characteristic $0$ with the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and uniformizer $\pi$. Let $k$ be the residue field of $K$ with $\text{card}(k)=q$. Let $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{E}$ be the $\pi$-adic completion of $\mathcal{O}_K((u))$, where $u$ is a fixed local co-ordinate. Then $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{E}$ is complete local ring with uniformizer $\pi$ and residue field $E:=k((u))$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{E}$. Let $\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}$ be the completion of the maximal unramified extension of $\mathcal{E}$. Let $\mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}$ denotes the ring of integers of $\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}$ is a complete local ring with uniformizer $\pi$ and residue field as $E^{sep}$. Then we have the following exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
 0\rightarrow k \rightarrow E^{sep}\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x^q-x}E^{sep}\rightarrow 0. 
 \end{equation*}
In other words, the sequence
\begin{equation*}
0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_K/\pi\mathcal{O}_K \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}/\pi \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x^q-x} \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}/\pi \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}\rightarrow0
\end{equation*} 
is exact as $k$ is the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $E^{sep}$ is the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}$.
Then by devissage the sequence
\begin{equation}
 0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_K/\pi^n\mathcal{O}_K \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}/\pi^n \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x^q-x} \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}/\pi^n \mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}\rightarrow0,
 \end{equation}
is exact for all $n\geq1$.
I don't want to say the word "by devissage" and want to write the explicit proof. I am trying to induction on $n$. but somehow I am not able to prove that the sequence is exact. Is there any other way to prove the exactness of this sequence.

Comment: Yes, it is a lift of Frobenius. We have a map, say $\varphi_q$ on $E^{sep}$, which sends $x$ to $x^q$, where $q$ is some power of $p$ for a fixed prime number $p$. Then we lift this map to $\mathcal{O}_{\widehat{\mathcal{E}^{ur}}}$.